# Not able to boot into installed Ubuntu!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-7

I bought a new acer netbook with pre-installed Win7 Professional. Now I installed Ubuntu 17.04 alongside it. Win is on the SSD C: and Ubuntu on the HDD D:. Legacy mode is turned on in BIOS. When I start the netbook, Windows starts automatically and I'm not able to choose an OS even though the HDD with Ubuntu is set first in the boot order. I now tried several things to work around, which did not work:

1. Using Windows cmd: **bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi**

   this command should set Grub as my standard bootloader and hopefully let me 
   choose an OS to boot to. I've got the message that the command executed 
   succesfully after execution, but after a reboot I still landed directly
   in Win7.
2. Using the ubuntu-terminal through the try-option on the Ubuntu-USB stick I
   installed Ubuntu from: 
    
   **sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair 

   sudo apt-get update 

   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair** 
    

   after the first command I got the error message: 
   Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~yannubuntu/ubuntu/boot-repair'.
   ERROR: '~yannubuntu' user or team does not exist.
3. I installed EasyBCD on Win7 and tried to add a new entry -> Linux/BSD to make
   Grub the default bootloader, but the button add entry is greyed out.

   ```
                         Is anyone able to help me?
   ```

Comment: If it's in Legacy mode - typical for Windows 7 - why are you now trying UEFI specific commands? And in Legacy/BIOS you can at most select a drive as the first boot device, not an Installed OS directly which is what happens with UEFI. So it seems you don't really know what you're doing?!?... Please use Boot Repair, do NOT apply any fix, but instead create a repost and post it.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. Im no expert, you're right. In 2. I mentioned that I tried boot repair and that that did not work or is there another way to do it?

Comment: You need internet connection in that live session.